Notifications not working when using Symfony UX Notify
I'm trying to set up notifications using Symfony UX Notify. I followed the documentation here: text and also used the documentation to set up the Mercure server: text
Here's how I configured my .env file:
###> symfony/mercure-notifier ###
MERCURE_DSN=mercure://default
###< symfony/mercure-notifier ###

###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
# See https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html#configuration
# The URL of the Mercure hub, used by the app to publish updates (can be a local URL)
MERCURE_URL=http://localhost:62635/.well-known/mercure
# The public URL of the Mercure hub, used by the browser to connect
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:62635/.well-known/mercure
# The secret used to sign the JWTs
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET= my jwt token here 
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

And here's how my notifier.yaml file looks like:
framework:
    notifier:
        chatter_transports:
            myMercureChatter: '%env(MERCURE_DSN)%'

To create notifications, I didn't use a Command but did it in the controller:
use Symfony\Component\Notifier\Bridge\Mercure\MercureOptions;
use Symfony\Component\Notifier\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\ChatMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Notifier\ChatterInterface;

class PageIndexController extends DefaultLayoutController
{
    public function __construct(
        ThemeHelper                             $theme,
        private readonly EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        private readonly IndexLinkRepository    $indexLinkRepository,
        private ChatterInterface                $chatter
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($theme);
    }

    // Other controller code

    // Method where I create the notification
    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_page_index_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag): Response
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $dto = new IndexLinksDTO();

        $form = $this->createForm(IndexLinksType::class, $dto, [
            'validation_groups' => ['basic']
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $dto->setUser($user);

            $cost = $parameterBag->get('page_index_cost');
            $totalCost = count($dto->getLinks()) * $cost;

            if ($user->getBalance() < $totalCost) {
                $this->addFlash('error', "You do not have enough tokens to index these links.
                                                        Indexing one link costs $cost tokens. Please top up your balance for quality
                                                        link indexing.");
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_page_index_new');
            }

            $entityManager = $this->entityManager;
            foreach ($dto->getLinks() as $link) {
                $indexLink = new IndexLink();
                $indexLink->setUser($user);
                $indexLink->setUrl($link->getUrl());
                $indexLink->setUserTokens($cost);
                $entityManager->persist($indexLink);
            }

            $user->setBalance($user->getBalance() - $totalCost);

            $entityManager->flush();

            $message = (new ChatMessage(
                'Success!!! Links added successfully for indexing.',
                new MercureOptions(['/index/link-indexing'])
            ))->transport('myMercureChatter');

            $this->chatter->send($message);


            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_page_index');
        }

        return $this->render('pages/page_index/create.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}

After that, I add this line to the TWIG template:
{{ stream_notifications(['/index/link-indexing']) }}

But when I add a link and it's successful, the notification doesn't come through. Can you please advise on what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing? Thank you!

Did you solve this problem since then? The problem should be the DSN address, but there is no any documentation on the internet, how to set that up.
